# Как отортировать список словарей по ключам?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, список, словари

Есть большой список, внутри которого 38 шт небольших словарей, по типу этого:

```
[{'name': 'Valera', 'age': 29}, {'name': 'Bob', 'age': 24}]
```

Как отсортировать это по всем ключам?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь лямбда функцией в качестве ключа для функции `sorted()`.

Пример:

```
In [142]: data =  [{'name': 'Valera', 'age': 29}, {'name': 'Bob', 'age': 24}]

In [143]: res = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x.get("name"))

In [144]: res
Out[144]: [{'name': 'Bob', 'age': 24}, {'name': 'Valera', 'age': 29}]
```